# How to structure firestore for a chat app

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am about to create a 1 to 1 chat app using firestore. Features are as follow :

- User can see a list of contacts that he chat with before.
- Number of unseen messages in a chat room.
- The last message and time.

I've thought of my `Message` model class as follow:

- messageId (UniqueId),
- senderId
- receiverId
- message
- time
- isSeen (bool, default value `false`)

Now lets say **user1** & **user2** made a conversation. I'm thinking of creating a separate root collection (`chats`) for chats in the following way :

```
chats(col) --> user1 --> chats(col) --> chatRoomId --> messages(col) --> messageId1
                                                                     --> messageId2
                                                                     --> messageId3
           --> user2 --> chats(col) --> chatRoomId --> messages(col) --> messageId1
                                                                     --> messageId2
                                                                     --> messageId3
```

The problem with this approach is that - there will be duplicate of data like same message to be stored for both the users separately. Also it'll be troublesome to update a message, as the message need to be updated in both location.

So keeping all the requirements in mind, what could be a better structure?

Comment: I´d suggest you to watch the YouTube Flutter & Firebase Series to get a better understanding, as there is not "the one and only solution". See [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v_hR4K4auoQ&list=PLl-K7zZEsYLluG5MCVEzXAQ7ACZBCuZgZ)

Answer (score 4):

Not sure whether it is the best method, but the way I structured firestore:

I have a `collection` called `groups` that is used for both group chat and for 1 on 1 chat. `groups` contains the following information:

- chatID (same as the ID of that particular `groups` row)
- members (userID's of all participating app users in that chat, also used for retrieve the chats for an user)
- recentMessageText
- recentMessageSentAt
- recentMessageSendBy
- readBy
- chatTitle (can be null, since not needed for 1 on 1)
- chatType (to indicate whether it is group or 1 on 1 chat)

In the ChatOverviewScreen I have a firestore query that only retrieves the documents from `groups` that contains his `userID` in `members` field.

So in the ChatOverviewScreen you can now display all the chats that the user has and you already know the ID reference needed to retrieve the messages that belong to a particular chat.

All the messages are stored in a collection called `chats` in which each documentID is also found in the `groups` document. Each document in `chats` contains a collection with all the `messages`.

The following link is also very useful: https://levelup.gitconnected.com/structure-firestore-firebase-for-scalable-chat-app-939c7a6cd0f5

Comment: This way, you won't be able to have a seen status for each message separately. Right?